# Linux change default battery capacity

Tags: linux, battery

Where can I change the estimated battery capacity on a Linux system?

Comment: x86 PC arch ? Do you mean the instantaneous value ? (whatever value you would be able to fiddle being likely to be almost instantly rewritten by your system) or the theoretical value when full ? (which is a data read in the EEPROM you would have to reprogram) BTW, everything starts from there  /sys/class/power_supply I don"t think entries that would be of interest to you are actually writeable.

Comment: change? You can only learn it. It's something your battery reports, you have no control over it.

Comment: It is a handheld rockchip cpu called odroid go super.  I believe the battery is just lipo with the built-in charge controller. no way to send data.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, everything related to batteries can be found under the `/sys/class/power_supply` directory tree.
So just browse into that directory or use possibly more convenient cli tools such as `upower` or `acpi`.

You should anyhow first have a look to the documentation regarding the [Linux Power Supply Class](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt). In which you could realise that there is no such a thing known as "***default** battery capacity*"

At least two data could appear related to you search :

**POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW** : Which is related to the instantaneous battery capacity and which obviously cannot be modified because irrespective of read-only files permissions, that value is almost certainly updated regularly by whatever BIOS / OS program.

**POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL** : This would indeed be interesting to change when the BIOS / OS get it all wrong after changing for new batteries. However, associated file ( `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/charge_full` ) is read-only as (related to x86 PC arches) it is likely to be the copy of some EEPROM hardcoded value.